# How to know which implicit fails to be resolved?

Tags: scala, logging, implicit, shapeless

I'm trying to create an automatic adapter from two case classes which have different fields with different types and different order.
It works, sometimes. It's just very difficult to debug and know which implicit fails to be resolved.
When the compiler fails to find an specific adapter I have to start playing in test with each one of the needed implicits and check which one is failing and why. Is there a way to mark why a given implicit method was a candidate and stopped being when trying to resolve the nested implicits?

Sorry if it sounds confusing!

```
private implicit def fromRecordAdapter
  [
  Source, SourceFields <: HList, SourceRecord <: HList, Target, TargetFields <: HList, TargetRecord <: HList,
  SelectedFields <: HList, AddedFields <: HList,
  SourceTakenProduct <: HList, TargetProduct <: HList, CommonRecord <: HList, AddedProduct <: HList,
  AddedRecord <: HList, UnorderedRecord <: HList
  ](
     implicit
     sourceRecord: LabelledGeneric.Aux[Source, SourceRecord]
     , sourceFields: Keys.Aux[SourceRecord, SourceFields]
     , targetRecord: LabelledGeneric.Aux[Target, TargetRecord]
     , recordFields: Keys.Aux[TargetRecord, TargetFields]
     , selectedFields: hlist.Intersection.Aux[SourceFields, TargetFields, SelectedFields]
     , addedFields: hlist.Diff.Aux[TargetFields, SelectedFields, AddedFields]
     , sourceTakenProduct: SelectAll.Aux[SourceRecord, SelectedFields, SourceTakenProduct]
     , targetProduct: SelectAll.Aux[TargetRecord, SelectedFields, TargetProduct]
     , addedProduct: SelectAll.Aux[TargetRecord, AddedFields, AddedProduct]
     , sourceToTargetMapper: TypeMapper[TargetProduct, SourceTakenProduct]
     , addedProductDefault: Lazy[DefaultValue[AddedProduct]]
     , commonRecord: ZipWithKeys.Aux[SelectedFields, TargetProduct, CommonRecord]
     , addedTagger: ZipWithKeys.Aux[AddedFields, AddedProduct, AddedRecord]
     , prepend: Prepend.Aux[CommonRecord, AddedRecord, UnorderedRecord]
     , align: hlist.Align[UnorderedRecord, TargetRecord]
   ): Adapter[Source, Target] = ...
```

In other words, I'd love to know in which parameter from that long list, the compiler stops and says, for example: "damn, there's no implicit for `sourceToTargetMapper:TypeMapper[TargetProduct, SourceTakenProduct]`"

That way I'd know where to start checking

Comment: Maybe try to use [splain](https://github.com/tek/splain)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
scalacOptions += "-Xlog-implicits"
```

Doesn't compiler write that if you try to call `fromRecordAdapter` explicitly?

```
def foo(implicit i: Int, b: Boolean, s: String, l: Long): Unit = ()

implicit val int: Int = 1
implicit val bool: Boolean = true

foo
//Error: could not find implicit value for parameter s: String

//Error: not enough arguments for method foo: (implicit i: Int, implicit b: Boolean, implicit s: String, implicit l: Long)Unit.
//Unspecified value parameter s.
```

Comment: I had this situation that the method was taking an implicit, but with a default value of null. So I was completely clueless when the implicit was actually not provided but no compiler error.

Comment: @texasbruce Well, that's a different situation. Actully this is the reason not to use implicit parameters with default values (sometimes it's considered as an [anti-pattern](https://wlangiewicz.com/2017/09/24/scala-patterns-to-avoid-implicit-arguments-with-default-values/)). It's better to define low-priority instances of type classes.

Comment: @texasbruce I'd try https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/e2930223069f5bbb303bb9460b97ae89 Unfortunately this prints message at runtime. If I wanted this to work at compile time, macro annotation `checkImplicits` would need to transform a method into def macro and transformed method and its application would need to be in different compilation units.

Comment: I agree with you this is not very safe. In fact I had this issue when I was using Akka: `def !(message: Any)(implicit sender: ActorRef = Actor.noSender): Unit`. I create a trait to mix in and forgot to declare an implicit ActorRef, but no error, and Akka is using noSender for the sender which took me a long time to debug...